# Smooth animation on Nav menubar in Twitter Bootstrap on mobile

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make the nav menu collapse and expand with a smooth animation rather than the jerk? Please check www.mobilewebbestpractices.com/index.html on small resolution to see what I would like to have?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's slow is that the system can't draw the frames quickly enough to make it a smooth animation.

The solution I've found to this problem is to stop using animation altogether.

You might try code similar to the following...

```
$(function() {
  $('.btn.btn-navbar').live('click', function() {
    $('.nav-collapse').toggle();
  });
});
```